# How to play a sound before splash in QT?

Tags: c++, qt

I want to play a sound within the splash but with the following code I get the splash to show up and then, only when the splash is gone, the sound to play. Can someone help me out? Thank you very much.

```cpp
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QMediaPlayer * splashSound = new QMediaPlayer;
    splashSound->setMedia(QUrl("qrc:/sfx/splash_sound.wav"));
    splashSound->play();

    QSplashScreen * mainSplash = new QSplashScreen;
    mainSplash->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/img/splash.png"));
    mainSplash->show();

    MainWindow w;

    QTimer::singleShot(2500, mainSplash, SLOT(close()));
    QThread::msleep(2500);

    w.show();

    return a.exec();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your call to `QThread::msleep(2500)`; it prevents the Qt event loop from executing (because `a.exec()` can't run until after it returns), and that in turn prevents the audio from playing.

The easy fix is to remove that line and the call to `w.show()`, and replace them with something like this:

```
QTimer::singleShot(2500, &w, SLOT(show()));
```

... That will cause your `MainWindow` widget to appear at the same time the splash-image disappears.